# XFCE focus snaps back to under cursor

Tags: xfce, focus

Not sure how to explain this. In many apps but not all, When there's a drop-down and the mouse pointer is inside it, I cannot navigate the list using keyboard. The focus in the list keeps snapping back to under the mouse cursor.

Also, (I think these are related) in some situations when there is a popup window with the input area, the input focus will jump back from popup back to where it was before the the popup.

I think this started when I enabled "Focus stealing prevention", but I since disabled it.

How do I get back to "normal" focus behaviour?

Comment: What versions are involved? What applications show the abnormal behaviour? Any other hint (applications doing intensive computation a the time, high memory use, ...?

Comment: xfce4 4.10.1. All apps. The only app I noticed so far where I can navigate menus using keys is Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow it occurred to me that this might be caused by `unclutter` utility I had recently installed. Turns out that is the culprit. Once I knew it, I was able to find that the issue has been reported already, for example here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3022/weird-mouse-problem.

Also, I found an alternative called `hhpc`: https://github.com/Aktau/hhpc. Going to give it a try.